# jQuery Code Inside PHP File Being Displayed While Using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Whilst trying to use AJAX for validation on my website, it is completely displaying to the user with exception of the PHP variables, the jquery code I am using for styling my inputs. I am trying to change the styles of my inputs accordingly and provide and error message, which is successful, however, the javascript code is also being displayed

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/template.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/template.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="startUp();">
    
<!-- Banner Image -->
<div id="banner"><img id="bannerImage" src="abcdefd.com.jpg" alt=""></div>

<!-- Body Wrapper -->
<div id="wrapper">
    
<!-- Content -->
<div id="content">
    
    <!-- <h2 id="title">Log In</h2> -->
    <form id="loginForm" method="post" action="config/config.index.php">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password"  placeholder="Password">
        <input class="click" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Log in">
    </form>
    <p id="err"></p>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loginForm").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var submit = $("#submit").val();
        $("#err").load("config/config.index.php",{
            email: email,
            password: password,
            submit:submit
        });
    });
});
```

**config.index.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        
        $errEmptyAll = false;
        $errEmptyEmail = false;
        $errEmptyPassword = false;
        $errEmail = false;
        
        if(empty($email) && empty($password)){
            echo 'Please enter an email and password.';
            $errEmptyAll = true;
        } else if(empty($email)){
            echo 'Please enter an email.';
            $errEmptyEmail = true;
        } else if(empty($password)){
            echo 'Please enter a password.';
            $errEmptyPassword = true;
        } else if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            echo 'Please enter a valid email.';
            $errEmail = true;
        }
    }
?>

<script>
    var errEmptyAll = "<?php echo $errEmptyAll; ?>";
    var errEmptyEmail = "<?php echo $errEmptyEmail; ?>";
    var errEmptyPassword = "<?php echo $errEmptyPassword; ?>";
    var errEmail = "<?php echo $errEmail; ?>";
    
    if(errEmptyAll == true){
        $("#email, #password").addClass("inputErr");
    }
    if(errEmptyEmail == true){
        $("#email").addClass("inputErr");
    }
    if(errEmptyPassword == true){
        $("#password").addClass("inputErr");
    }
    if(errEmail == true){
        $("#email").addClass("inputErr");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Is the PHP code inside the same file as the javascript one?

Comment: Also, read your own code... `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` so, yeah, SUBMIT, but anyways you're expecting those variables to automagically  be passed to JS on a non-submit...

Comment: Yes it is. I am using AJAX to send the data to a php config file.

Comment: If yes than simply use an `exit; ?>` instead of just `?>`  But then, don't expect those variables to be passed to JS.

Comment: I would like the variables to be passed still. How can I do this?

Comment: You should not have any JS in that PHP file - to start with. let me see what you're actually doing with that code in details... Could you explain a bit more?!

Comment: I edited the post and added all of my files.

Comment: h, I got it. Your issue is quite simple actually. Don't use any JS in config.php, and don't use `.load()`, rather use $.ajax to POST your form payload, than inside that config.php after you validate - return a json_encoded response back to AJAX. Read that JSON inside the succes callback in JS: `{status: "success/error", message:"OK/This or that was invalid"}`

Comment: I'll make you an example soon

Comment: I would very much appreciate this, Roko. Trying my best to understand AJAX.

Comment: Added an example. Let me know if you need some code clarification.

Answer (score 0):

- The config PHP file should not have any JS at all.
- Don't use `.load()`. **Use `$.ajax` to send POST data and listen for server responses**.
- Build a `json_encode` response on PHP which will be returned to the browser via AJAX. Read the response data (from PHP) in JavaScript jQuery via the `:success` property or in the `.done()` method of `$.ajax`

**index.html**

```html
<form id="loginForm" method="post" action="config/config.index.php">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Log in</button>
</form>
<p id="err"></p>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script srrc="index.js"></script>
```

**index.js**

```js
jQuery(($) => { // DOM ready and $ alias in scope

    const $err = $("#err");

    $("#loginForm").on("submit", function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault(); // prevent browser submit

        $(this).find(`[name]`).removeClass("inputErr");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            url: this.action, // from form action value
            data: $(this).serialize(),
        }).done((res) => {
            // res is the JSON Response from PHP
            console.log(res); // Do with this whatever you want. i.e:
            if (res.errors.length) {
                $err.text(res.errors.join(", "));
                res.fields.forEach(field => {           
                    $(`[name="${field}"]`).addClass("inputErr");
                });
            } else {
                // SUCCESS!!!
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**config/config.index.php**

```php
<?php

$response = (object)[
    "status" => "error",
    "errors" => [],
    "fields" => [], // IDs of fields with error
];


if (
    $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST" &&
    isset($_POST["email"]) && 
    isset($_POST["password"])
) {

    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $passwordEmpty = empty($password);
    $emailEmpty = empty($email);
    $emailInvalid = !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

    if ($passwordEmpty) :
        $response->errors[] = "Invalid Password";
        $response->fields[] = "password";
    endif;

    if ($emailEmpty) :
        $response->errors[] = "Empty Email";
        $response->fields[] = "email";
    elseif ($emailInvalid) :
        $response->errors[] = "Invalid Email";
        $response->fields[] = "email";
    endif;

    if (empty($response->errors)) :
        $response->status = "success";
    endif;
}

echo json_encode($response);
exit;
```